# R cannot find %do% function

Tags: r, parallel-foreach

I am trying to learn how to use the parallel foreach loops in R:

I tried running the following code:

```
testParForEach<-function(){

#testing a parallel for each loop

#to parallelize loop:
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)
cl<-makeCluster(2)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

resultdf <- foreach(i=1:8, .combine='rbind') %dopar% {
 foreach(j=1:2, .combine='c') %do% {
  l <- runif(1, i, 100)
  i + j + l  
 }
}



return(resultdf)

#close cluster
stopCluster(cl)


 }
```

(which I got from another post on Stackoverflow) but am getting the error:

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "konnte Funktion "%do%" nicht finden"

which means "could not find function %do%".
Has anyone seen this error before?

Answer (score 0):

That is because `%do%` is defined in the `foreach` package. The outer parallelization via `foreach` is starting separate R processes (in your case 2) which independently execute the to-be-parallelized code. But in those processes no `foreach` package is loaded. This is done via the `.packages`-paramter of the `foreach`-function.

An example you can find [here](http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/parallel-computing-r-windows-using-dosnow-foreach/).